# Adding a menu to classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I want to add a menu or a button which allows a teacher to click on that to view charts and reports that is specific for a particular course. Is there a way one can add menus or buttons inside Google Classroom ? Similar to Stream, Students and About, I would like to add Reports as an item on the dashboard. When the user clicks on Reports I want to show graphs and information on the dashboard ideally without leaving Google Classroom if possible.

Any help and guidance is more appreciated.

Regards

ajith

Comment: You will have to implement your own code for this. You need to know Javascript and HTML. For example inside your button functions, trigger the [Collection.courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses). There are a bunch of  tutorials on the web for creating menus like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)

Comment: Thank you but very much for your comment. I was wondering whether Google Classroom would allow me to do it or not. Then how do other customers purchase this module etc.